# Axis2 to Apache CXF using XMLBeans data bindings

Tags: java, apache, ant, cxf, apache-axis

I am new to web service and am working in a migration project. I am suppose to carry on the migration from Axis2 to Apache CXF 3 using XMLBeans data bindings. I would like to know what are the changes that is required to be made (A migration guide would be helpful). As a build tool We are using Ant, annotation based Spring 4.

Comment: Can anyone Please help me on this!

Answer (score 0):

Xmlbeans is no longer being maintained.  You may want to consider jaxb instead

Comment: A problem I ran into however is that Jax-B didnt seem to handle the xsd:anyType very well or at all.  I'm giving XMLBeans a go to see if it works better but now getting the dreaded "JAXB can't handle interfaces." exceptions which I'm now trying to figure out how to use the xmlBeans binding instead